# html in JTextPane - strange box appear for tags

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I haven't used HTML in JTextPane before and playing with this today. I come across with strange output.

Here is my simple code, `htmlStr` contains contains a tag `<aa>`  :

```
public class HtmlInJTextPaneTest extends JFrame {
    private JTextPane jtp;
    private String htmlStr= "<html><body><b>What is this</b> <aa > ?? </body></html>";
    public HtmlInJTextPaneTest() {
        jtp = new JTextPane();
        jtp.setContentType("text/html");
        jtp.setText(htmlStr);
        //jtp.setEditable(false);

        //jFrame setup
        add(jtp);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HtmlInJTextPaneTest();
    }
}
```

The output of this is :

[image]

I don't know why the box (seems like input field) appeared with tag name `aa` in it?

It disappears when I set editable false on `JTextPane` object `jtp`.

```
    jtp.setEditable(false);
```

Can you please explain it?

Comment: Looks like the HTML parser is interpreting the "<aa >" wrongly. If you remove the angular brackets around "aa", this shouldn't happen. I am not sure if the parser is comparable to parsers in standard browsers.

Comment: I believe that the HTML parser used by JTextPane to render html string can not be compared to functionality of standard browsers . But, I wonder why they interpreted <aa> into the box like that?

Comment: I'm guessing that is just JTextPane's fallback for unknown HTML tags.  I did some searching and saw an interesting comment on this page: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4765240.  Check the very last comment, which suggests a possible fix for that fallback behavior.  If it works for you, then I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this http://java-sl.com/custom_tag_html_kit.html as example of custom tag support in `HTMLEditorKit`.